# 2 monitors, 1 TV mirroring either one. TV won't display signal when plugged into DVI port.

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, tv, splitter

I'm trying to get 3 monitors working on my GeForce GTX 560Ti graphics card on Vista 64-bit. I am aware that I can't run 3 displays on this card. That's fine because either monitor and my TV could be a mirror image. I have one primary monitor on a DVI port, and I have a splitter on the second DVI port. The splitter is connected to my second monitor and my TV with a HDMI adapter. The TV will not work when connected into the DVI port, even if I unplug my secondary monitor. The TV only will show an image if it's connected into the HDMI mini port on my graphics card. I can't split my primary and secondary monitor obviously.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, or how I can set this up?

Comment: so the real problem here is your HDMI input tv is not working with the DVI-HDMI adaption?  What "splitter" type are you using?

Comment: @Psychogeek - Yeah that's right. My splitter is DVI to DVI then an HDMI adapter on one end which goes to an HDMI to DVI cable into the TV.

Comment: now I get confused again. Where do you adapt the DVI-HDMI? Is this a single adapter or a Cable that is doing the adaption (or both)?   Still dont know what you mean by "splitter". because splitter could be a "switch" or it could be electronic mix, or just crashed together and only work one at a time anyway.  Would be cool to see pictures of this or links to the models your applying.

Comment: The splitter is a simple cable: 
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16882750035
This is the adapter :
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814999010
This is a similar DVI to HDMI cable to the one I have:
http://www.amazon.com/DVI-HDMI-Cable-6ft-Male-Male/dp/B0002CZHN6

It is confusing isn't it. But the plugs all fit!  So I have that going for me :).

Comment: slowly (and preferably edited into your question) if the splitter is not in the scenario at all here. . A) Can you get the DVI-HDMI adapter to work, from the card to one TV? . B) Can you get the adapter cable to work from the card to the TV? .  The splitter is a crash together, and it is only going to work in certian situations :-(  Mabey it works based  on a dual link DVI? because they indicate 2 lower res signals? I would prefer a hard switch, if I had ever done that.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DVI